# SonarQube ,sql server DB with Team city Plugin - Throwing "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (I/O Error: DB server closed connection.)" error

Tags: java, teamcity, sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube  with Sql server. I have Team city in place and I would like to integrate Sonar runner with TC for my c# projects. I have done following things to achieve the same.

1) setup the sonarserver  with sql server DB (DB name Sonar  with sql server authentication).  server could create all required datatables. When hit http://[machinename]:9000. I could see dashboard page.

2)Installed TC sonar runner plugin. Have given sonar server address,DB server address with user name and pwd.

3) I have setup sonar runner build step in TC project along with project build step. When I run it, step 1 ( i.e build is successful). While executing step 2 ( Sonar runner), it is getting aborted with an error  :

> **Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (I/O Error: DB server closed connection.)**

4) I have checked for connection string, user name , pwd, Sql server network configuration ( TCP, named pipes.. etc all enabled ), No firewall.  Most importantly from same machine other DB in same DB server  is getting accessed well. It a proof that DB Host ( server) has no issue in terms of firewalls, network protocols etc..

Here is the  build log.

> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] 10:12:03.012 INFO  - Load global referentials...
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] 10:12:03.233 INFO  - Load global referentials
>   done: 223 ms
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] 10:12:03.236 INFO  - User cache:
>   C:\Users\teamcity_svc.sonar\cache
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] 10:12:03.243 INFO  - Install plugins
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] 10:12:03.429 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] 10:12:03.435 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for
>   jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[My DB server
>   name]:1433/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor;
>
> ### [10:12:03][Step 2/2] INFO:
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>
> ### [10:12:03][Step 2/2] INFO:
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] Total time: 1.042s
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] Final Memory: 3M/15M
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>
> ### [10:12:03][Step 2/2] INFO:
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR: Caused by: Fail to connect to database
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR: Caused by: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (I/O Error: DB server closed connection.)
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR: Caused by: I/O Error: DB server closed
>   connection.
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR: Caused by: DB server closed connection.
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR:
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors,
>   re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X
>   switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
>
> [10:12:03][Step 2/2] Step Sonar runner for MKS (SonarQube Runner)
>   failed

What am I missing here ? I tried every way but error remains same. Any one faced the same issue and has solution ?

Comment: I have checked server event logs where SQL server is hosted. It is showing   "The login packet used to open the connection is structurally invalid; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the client library. [CLIENT: IP address of client]" .   Google results explains that this may be due to token size which happens in windows authentication. But I am NOT using windows authentication in sonarqube plugin.